# How to select Overdue Rows with Date Frequencies?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, date, where

```
+------------------------+--------+
|  Invoice_id | due_date | amount |
+-------------+----------+--------+
|  20         |2020-01-18|  1250  |
+-------------+----------+--------+
| 21          |2020-01-15|  1335  |
+-------------+----------+--------+
```

Get all Records with date passed `n days and its multiple serires`
like below...

for example n=5

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` 
WHERE `due_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 days)
OR due_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 days)
OR due_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 15 days)`
```

but i want to make it universal for any `n value`

> **Note:** mySQL version in my machine is 5.*

Comment: please avoid use of `WITH` as my mySQL version is lower than 8.*

Comment: Please add this info into your question text into the same beginning. Proper tag added.

Comment: You only want every 5th day?  That's not what your example output shows.  Or is that not output?

Comment: @RickJames i want every 5th day

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS 
( SELECT @starting_deviation num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT num + @delta_deviation
  FROM cte 
  WHERE num < @final_deviation )
SELECT * 
FROM invoices
JOIN cte ON invoices.due_date = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL cte.num DAY
```

For the query from the question `@starting_deviation := 5`, `@delta_deviation := 5` and `@final_deviation := 15`. These values may be specified literally (inserted immediately into the query instead of variables), transferred via variables values assignement or taken from some service table.

---

In MySQL 5+ you must generate the numbers table in a subquery or use external static numbers table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoices
JOIN ( SELECT 5 num UNION ALL
       SELECT 10 UNION ALL
       SELECT 15 ) cte ON invoices.due_date = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL cte.num DAY
```

> i want to add is my frequency is not upto 3 series. it can be more than 3 maybe any number.... so for example if n is 5 and i want 10 frquesnces means 5,10, 15, 20......, 50

Use numbers generator. For example it can be (shown generator may give up to 64 values):

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoices
JOIN ( SELECT 5 * (1 + t1.num + t2.num * 4 + t3.num + 16) num
       FROM (SELECT 0 num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t1,
            (SELECT 0 num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t2,
            (SELECT 0 num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t3
     ) cte ON  invoices.due_date = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL cte.num DAY
WHERE cte.num BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

Comment: `WITH` only works in mysql version 8.0 or higher. while I'm using mysql version 5.*

Comment: @MateeGojra Updated with the code applicable to 5.x version.

Comment: I have added version info... but one more thing i want to add is my frequency is not upto 3 series. it can be more than 3 maybe any number.... so for example if `n is 5` and i want 10 frquesnces means 5,10, 15, 20......, 50

Comment: @MateeGojra Generate as many values as you need. Sample code added.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (DATEDIFF(due_date, CURDATE) % 5) = 0
```

Will filter down to today and any multiple of 5 days before or after today.  Use that as the basic building block for the rest of your query.